# How do i show the values of y axis on my Oxy plot chart(series)

Tags: wpf, label, axis, oxyplot

I'm so sorry for my bad english but I need your help now.
So...I'm working with wpf projects and I need to draw series charts from number of values(points). For example it:

```
series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(new DateTime(2016, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0)), 12));            
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(new DateTime(2016, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0)), 12.5));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(new DateTime(2016, 3, 8, 0, 0, 0)), 12.8));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(new DateTime(2016, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0)), 12.4));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(new DateTime(2016, 3, 20, 0, 0, 0)), 12.9));
```

As we can see at the bottom screen, OxyPlot draw labels at line from X axis. I need to show on line the values of Y axis.
What shoud I do? Thanks.

[What I Need to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOEy3.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OxyPlot: How to use the axis label formater and show Y labels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897192/oxyplot-how-to-use-the-axis-label-formater-and-show-y-labels)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `highcharts` for it. Though it's not officially supported with `wpf` but you can find your way out on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402689/dotnet-highcharts-is-there-any-way-to-use-it-in-winform-application).